# Конфликт header с .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Всем привет , есть такой код в `.htaccess` который убирает расширение php с адресной строки , и позволяет писать в адресной строке адрес типа `example.com/index` вместо `example.com/index.php`
Все работает на Ура , только есть одно но , он как-то конфликтует с функцией `php header` (переадресация)
стоит мне его убрать , header работает как и должен , но с его присутствием , отказывается перенаправлять , может кто знает как поправить , либо может есть у кого другой код выполняющий ту же задачу для .htaccess?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ([^\s]*)\.php(\?[^\s]*)?
RewriteRule (.*) %1 [R=301,L]
```

вот код `header`

```
if (password_verify($pass001, $pass000) && password_verify($log001, $log000))  {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['shaccesforadmpanhard'] = true;
    header("Location: adminpan.php");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

session_start и header должен быть применен до echo. Попробуйте так:

```
if (password_verify($pass001, $pass000) && password_verify($log001, $log000))  {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['shaccesforadmpanhard'] = true;
    header("Location: adminpan.php");
    echo 'Password is valid!';
}
```

Не понятно, с какой целью применяется echo, если используется редирект. Так же, мне кажется, что Location должен быть /adminpan без .php

Comment: попробовал не сработало , дело не в этом , без вышеприведенного кода .htaccess , скрипт php работает который я написал

Comment: проблема в самом .htaccess коде , так как без него все работает на ура